# How to grab a substring from a given string?

Tags: python, string, slice, string-operations

Basically I have following strings and I want to grab a sub-string from them.

```
input: RT4_MANGO_AF
output: MANGO

input:  RT4_DF5_WE_APPLE_AF 
output: APPLE 

input: TF_WE_BANANA_AF
output: BANANA

input: RT4_DF5_ORANGE_AF
output: ORANGE
```

Note the hint here is that, the last 3 chars will remain `_AF` and I want to grab the sub-string before  `_AF` and after the last-but-one `_` symbol.

I have the following code which does the same, but I feel it's not optimal. Is there a way to optimize this code? or can I get optimized code?

```
sd = 'ER5_WE_APPLE_AF'
m = sd[:-3]
for i in range(len(m)):
    if m[i] == "_":
        si = i
    else:
        continue
m = m[si+1:]
print(m)
```

Comment: `print(sd.split('_')[-2])` will do it.  Split the string into words on the underscores, and grab the next-to-the-last one.

Comment: That, or `sd.rsplit('_', 2)[-2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply writing `print(sd.split('_')[-2])` will do the trick. We can do this since the end of the string will always contain "_AF", so we can grab the substring that comes before that.